# Working with NSData in swift

Tags: pointers, swift, nsdata

So I've figured out how to extract NSData in swift but i'm getting confused with regards to setting it:

```
var testBytes : [Byte] = [0x14, 0x00, 0xAB, 0x45, 0x49, 0x1F, 0xEF, 0x15,     
                          0xA8, 0x89, 0x78, 0x0F, 0x09, 0xA9, 0x07, 0xB0,
                          0x01, 0x20, 0x01, 0x4E, 0x38, 0x32, 0x35, 0x56,
                          0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x00]

var msgData = NSData(bytes: testBytes, length: testBytes.count)

println("\(msgData)")


var length : Int = testBytes.count

var out: NSInteger = 0

let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(msgData.bytes)
var bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: 28)
```

So if i want to access a specific byte I can get it with something like:

```
let targetAddress = UInt32(bytes[2]) << 16 |
    UInt32(bytes[3]) << 8 |
    UInt32(bytes[4]) << 0
```

Now say I wanted to set a value with something like:

```
bytes[11] = UInt8(UInt32(bytes[11]) | 0x0FF)
```

I get an error of `Cannot assign the result of this expression)`.  I tried also using `&bytes[11]` which doesn't seem to fly either.

I'm assuming this is because the array uses an unsafe buffer pointer.  Is there an easy call that I've some how glossed over to make the assignment work correctly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to *modify* the bytes retrieved from the `NSData`
object, then you should *copy* the bytes into a separate array

```
var bytes = [UInt8](count: msgData.length, repeatedValue: 0)
msgData.getBytes(&bytes, length: bytes.count)

bytes[11] = UInt8(UInt32(bytes[11]) | 0x0FF)
```

`NSData` is an immutable object, and

```
let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(msgData.bytes)
```

is a constant pointer, so you must not modify the pointed-to data.

Alternatively, use a *mutable* data object from the beginning:

```
var msgData = NSMutableData(bytes: testBytes, length: testBytes.count)

let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(msgData.mutableBytes)
var bytes = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: msgData.length)

bytes[11] = UInt8(UInt32(bytes[11]) | 0x0FF)
```

Note the usage of `msgData.mutableBytes` instead of `msgData.bytes`.
 This will modify the data in `msgData` directly.