# How to parse bluetooth peripheral characteristic value

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have no prior experience of working with bluetooth sensors and parsing raw values. I am trying to parse the characteristic value but I am not really sure how to actually read and parse it. Data description of the characteristic I am trying to parse is here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.csc_measurement.xml

Here is following code

```
   func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        parseData(characteristic.value)
    }

    private func parseData(data: NSData?) {
        if let data = data {
            var values = [UInt8](count:data.length, repeatedValue:0)
            data.getBytes(&values, length:data.length)

            print(values)
        }
    }
```

The output looks something like this

```
[2, 14, 0, 16, 56]
[2, 16, 0, 249, 62]
[2, 18, 0, 175, 191]
[2, 23, 0, 90, 195]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 251, 206]
[1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 145, 208]
[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 212]
[1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 25, 217]
```

Now first, I am not really sure if I have to parse this into UInt8, that's the part which is not clear and I cannot understand what bluetooth website says coz there are UInt32 and UInt16 variables. How would I parse that from a single raw data. I think I am getting this whole thing wrong but thats what I am trying to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234706/working-with-nsdata-in-swift and potentially `subDataWithRange:`.